# AttributeError: 'MovieSerializer' object has no attribute 'id' + Serialization

Tags: json, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

The perfect scenario would be to use the RatingSerializer inside the MovieSerializer but since it is below the actual mvserializer code, i cannot use it. Therefore, I started to serialize the rating object using json.dumps() and it looks very ugly after serialization.

serializers.py

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = 15414
    director = PersonSerializer()
    rating = serializers.SerializerMethodField() # I want to use here RatingSerializer()
    
    def get_rating(self, obj):
        r = list(Rating.objects.filter(movie_id=self.id).values())[0]
        r['rating'] = float(r['rating'])
        return json.dumps(r)

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'director', 'rating']


class RatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movie = MovieSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        fields = ['id', 'movie', 'rating', 'votes']
```

result, the rating field is serialized very bad

```
  {
        "id": 16906,
        "title": "Frivolinas",
        "director": {
            "id": 2014,
            "name": "Iron Eyes Cody",
            "birth": 1907
        },
        "rating": "{\"id\": 1, \"movie_id\": 15414, \"rating\": 5.4, \"votes\": 12}"
    },
```

is there a way I can use RatingSerializer inside MovieSerializer?
Doing this way (my way), i also cannot find the actual id in the get_rating method, i have hard coded it.

Comment: You can not use the `RatingSerializer` at the bottom, since that would result in an infinite recursion: serializing the movie would serialize all the related ratings with the corresponding movies with the corresponding ratings, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should filter on the `.id` of the `obj`, not of `self`, since `self` is the *serializer*, not the object the serializer is working on:

```
def get_rating(self, obj):
    r = Rating.objects.filter(movie_id=obj.id).values()[0]
    r['rating'] = float(r['rating'])
    return r
```

It is however likely better to work with a `RatingSerializer`. You can *not* use the `RatingSerializer` at the bottom, since that would result in an infinite recursion: serializing the movie would serialize all the related ratings with the corresponding movies with the corresponding ratings, etc.

We thus can make a simple (flat) serializer for the `Rating`s, and work with:

```
class SimpleRatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        # no movie
        fields = ['id', 'rating', 'votes']

class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    director = PersonSerializer()
    rating = SimpleRatingSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'director', 'rating']
```

Comment: AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `rating` on serializer `MovieSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Movie` instance.   
Original exception text was: 'Movie' object has no attribute 'rating'.       I get this error if trying your solution

Comment: @Brat: but what is the `related_name` of the `ForeignKey` of the `movie` in the `Rating` model. It looks like your `rating` in `fields` is then simply not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually this works fine.

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    director = PersonSerializer()
    rating = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    votes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_rating(self, obj):
        r = list(Rating.objects.filter(movie_id=obj.id).values())[0]
        return json.dumps(float(r['rating']))

    def get_votes(self, obj):
        r = list(Rating.objects.filter(movie_id=obj.id).values())[0]
        return json.dumps(r['votes'])

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'director', 'rating', 'votes']
```